# PHP How to insert multiple checkbox value into database

Tags: php, html, database, checkbox

**UPDATE -**
Problem has been solved due to a typo mistake at **$param_keyword**

I have created a form which accepts multiple checkbox value to insert to the database. My database connection is working fine i can insert name, but not checkboxes. I am not sure where the problem is because there is no error and i can see the string of the checkboxes.

After clicking the submit button, i print the keywordArr to see the values:

**housekeeping,chemical and dangerous material** Something went wrong. Please try again later.

PHP Query

```
<?php
require_once("includes/dbConfig.php");

// get input when form is submitted, using the clean functon to clean inputs
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

//name validation
if (empty(clean($_POST["name"]))) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
} else {
    $name = clean($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
        $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
}

$keyword = $_POST["keyword"];
echo $keywordArr = implode(",", $keyword);

// check input erros before inserting in database
if (empty($nameErr)) {

    // Prepare a INSERT statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO site (name,keyword) VALUES (?,?)";

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_name, $param_keyword);

        // Set parameters
        //$param_id = $id;
        $param_name = $name;
        $parm_keyword = $keywordArr;

        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {

            // Alert to redirect
            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                    window.alert('Successfully Sent!')
                    window.location.href='index.php';
                    </SCRIPT>");
        } else {
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

HTML Form

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" 
value="housekeeping" name="keyword[]">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Housekeeping</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2" 
value="procedure" name="keyword[]">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Procedure (PTW,JSA, 
Inspection)</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck3" 
value="chemical and dangerous material" name="keyword[]">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck3">Chemical & Dangerous 
Material</label>
</div>      
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck4" 
value="confined space" name="keyword[]">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck4">Confined 
Space</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck5" 
value="scaffolding" name="keyword[]">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck5">Scaffolding</label>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You have a typo here - $parm_keyword

Comment: I am unable to see any field in your form which sends `$_POST["name"]` data. which you used as `$name`. As well as `$param_keyword !==$parm_keyword `. TYPO mistake .`a` is missing in second variable

Comment: @KarloKokkak Oh now i see why thanks alot! i feel so dumb now... I spent almost the whole morning solving it

Comment: @AlivetoDie i didnt want to include the Name html as it is redundant

Comment: @user3111115  since it's a TYPO mistake so better to delete your question now. As it will not serve any useful purpose to anybody.Thanks

Comment: You could use an array for the keywords, and use the keys as form values.  If submitted, check you have correct keys, so you confine keywords to a predefined list.  Otherwise user can enter any old keywords.

Comment: Can you please tell me that you want to insert multiple record or single?

Comment: @Dani my problem has been solve due to a typo..
 it is a multiple record

Answer (score 0):

The name of the checkboxes could be different as they are not radio button for each of the input tag.Then in your PHP file get each value using $_POST["keyword1"],$_POST["keyword2"] and so on then check if it is selected by the following code

```
If($_POST["keyword1"]=='on'){
// Your Code
}
```

Similarly check for each checkbox create whatever string you want and insert it into DB.

Answer (score 0):

I will be deleting this post as it was a typo mistake here **$param_keyword**

As i am unable to delete the post, this problem has already been solved and the insertion of values into database works well